# Preferred domain setting functionality in Google Search Console is broken

Tags: google-search-console

I'd like to set a preferred domain for my website but *saving changes* is taking too long than the usual. Is there something wrong?

When I reloaded the page, it went back to the default setting. I really want to set the domain for canonicalization purposes.

Please see attached image:

[image: Site Settings > Preferred Domain]

Comment: it might some technical glitch. If you setup proper 301 redirection then you don't need to setup preferred domain in search console. I am not seeing what the URL is but hope it is same domain name (subdomain is fine) not a different domain name.

Comment: Was this a google domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Thanks for all the inputs. I've recently found out how to resolve the issue.*

I added another variation of my website to Google Search Console before going to the settings and selecting the preferred domain. It seems like **Google** chooses either your **www.mywebsite.com** or **http://mywebsite.com**.

In my experience, I only added as property the www.mywebsite.com. When I went to settings to change the preferred domain, the problem occurred.

Then recently, I added the http://mywebsite.com version and checked to see if I can already set the preferred domain.

And, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the functionality is broken for one of my domains as well.   I see the same behavior that you do.  When I click on "Display URLs as example.com", a save button appears.   When I click "Save" I see the "Saving changes" message that never actually resolves.   If I click the "Dismiss" button or refresh the page the setting was not applied.

[image]
This is clearly a bug in Google Search Console and Google needs to be involved to fix it.  The official way to report a bug in Search Console to Google is to post about it in their webmaster help forums: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/webmasters   Their community leaders can escalate issues to Google staff to be fixed.  I did a quick search and couldn't find that anybody had reported the issue yet.  I took the liberty of reporting it there: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/_USyOGeq3_E   Hopefully Google will fix the issue soon.

Comment: Was this a google domain?